# Codeigniter 3, does Binding parameters protect me from SQL injection?

Tags: php, codeigniter, parameters, binding

Sorry to ask such a stupid question. I'm new to Codeigniter. I found that Codeigniter doesn't support prepared statements. I know that if you don't use prepared statements, you can easily get sql injected. Im here just to ask experienced user with Codeigniter. How do you write your queries? Inside my model i got the following code that works.

```
        public function get_credentials($userid){
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = ?", array($userid));
        return $query;
    }
```

I think my website is safe while i'm using the bind parameter above. But i still need some advice to do this as secure as possible. I never access my models from my views folder. I only access them from my controllers and pass the data to my pages. If there is something more that i need to know please give me advice, thank you for your time.

Comment: i suggest you read the "Query Builder Class" in the User Guide, this is the recommended way to run SQLs.

Comment: I second @ilias-sp .. Query Builder handles escaping internally and is the safest way to run queries when using codeigniter

Comment: CI 4.x: [Prepared Queries](https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/queries.html#prepared-queries)